# Is there any function to add space in PL/SQL

Tags: plsql

In T-SQL, SPACE() function is used to add spaces to a string. For e.g.

```
@s = 'He' + space(5) + 'llo'
```

Output

```
He     llo
```

So is there any function in PL/SQL that is equivalent to SPACE()?

Thank you.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use RPAD or LPAD functions

```
select 'He'  || rpad(' ',5,' ') || 'llo'
from dual;
/
```

or in PL/SQL it would be:

```
declare
  x varchar2(20);
begin
  x:= 'He'  || rpad(' ',5,' ') || 'llo';
end;
/
```

Answer (score 3):

Jeffrey using `rpad(' ',n,' ')` gives `n+1` spaces

```
select RPAD('A',3,'-')||RPAD(' ',4,' ')||RPAD('B',5,'-') from dual
```

Output

```
A--    B----
```

After `A--` and before `B`, you will find 5 spaces instead of 4.

Answer (score 0):

In Oracle, you can emulate the `space()` function with:

```
rpad(' ',n,' ')
```

Where `n` is one less than the total length of the string of spaces you want.

E.g. for a string of 40 spaces:

```
select rpad(' ',39,' ') as "40 spaces" from dual
```

`dual` is a dummy table you can use to test calculations and string manipulations without extracting from a real life table.

Comment: try again... `select length(rpad(' ',39,' ')) from dual;` returns 39, not 40.